# Looking for the name of a Werewolf thriller set in or near the Arctic

Tags: story-identification, horror, werewolf

Back in the early 90s I read a book that had **won an award** and was an excellent example of writing to create a sense of dread. I have had trouble finding this book again and unfortunately can remember neither the title of the book nor the author.

The book would have been **written in the early 1990s** **(no later than 1993)** or in the late 1980s. It was a **werewolf** story in which the male protagonist was the werewolf. The setting was in or near the **Arctic** at a **remote mining operation** that was called something like **"Teamwerk"** (a foreign spelling of Teamwork). There was a **female supporting character** who was the romantic interest of the werewolf protagonist, and the **estranged husband (boyfriend?)** of the woman formed the third part of the love triangle. All three of these characters were located at the remote mining operation. The mood was skilfully created by the writer, one of impending dread, loneliness and isolation. Juxtaposed with this was the romance that developed between the woman and the werewolf protagonist, which, if I remember correctly, was quite sultry.

Not the sort of book I normally read but I really enjoyed it and the mood has stayed with me all these years. I'm hoping someone else has read it and can let me know the details. Many thanks!

Comment: Not the same, but this sounds very similar to the [*Red Riding Hood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Riding_Hood_(2011_film)) movie.

Comment: Do you remember the names of any of the characters at all? Also, any idea what kind of award it won?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember any of the names as I read this well over 20 years ago. I don't remember the award except that it was a literary award from Europe. Sorry, that's all I've got.